# Deleting file in ceph does not free up disk space

Tags: filesystems, nfs, ceph, distributed-filesystems, cephfs

Ceph version: 16.2.13 (pacific) (I know that pacific is deprecated but the whole environment is legacy (like centos 7.3). I am not authorized to upgrade as well.) The cluster has 6 servers (22 osds, 97 pgs). There is a CephFS which is exported through NFS. The clients are accessing the cluster through NFSv4.1 (NFS-Ganesha). The following command is used in the client to mount:

```
# mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,noauto,soft,sync,proto=tcp 172.20.0.31:/exports /cephmnt
```

I copied a folder (around 5.2GB) to /cephmnt.

```
# cp sysdir /cephmnt
```

So the space expanded as expected (after checking the output of `df -Th` and `ceph df detail`).

```
# df -Th | grep -i ceph
172.20.0.31:/exports    nfs4    26T    5.2G    26T    1%    /cephmnt

# ceph df | grep -i cephfs
cephfs.new_storage.meta    8    32    26 MiB    28      79 MiB    0      25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.data    9    32    5.2 GiB   1.42k   15 GiB    0.02   25 TiB
```

However, when I delete the folder the space did not shrink back.

```
# rm -rf sysdir

# df -Th | grep -i ceph
172.20.0.31:/exports    nfs4    26T    5.2G    26T    1%    /cephmnt

# ceph df | grep -i cephfs
cephfs.new_storage.meta    8    32    26 MiB     28       79 MiB    0       25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.data    9    32    5.2 GiB    1.42k    15 GiB    0.02    25 TiB
```

I am able to see the list of objects in the data pool with:

```
# rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls
```

I am quite new to ceph so I don't know whether this is a normal behaviour in ceph or not although I suspect the latter so I did try some digging.

Snapshots are disbled and there are no existing snapshots for both pools:

```
# ceph fs set new_storage allow_new_snaps false
# rados -p cephfs.new_storage.meta lssnap
0 snaps
# rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data lssnap
0 snaps
```

I had read somewhere that bluestore in OSDs is will automatically remove unusable data if `bdev_async_discard` and `bdev_enable_discard` are set to true so I had set them

```
# ceph config get osd bdev_async_discard
true
# ceph config get osd bdev_enable_discard
true
```

But this has no effect. I have unmounted and mounted the nfs share several times (once even leaving it unmounted overnight) but whenever I mount back `df -Th` and `ceph df` still show the same space to be occupied. I `cd` into the /cephmnt directory and gave the sync command. Still no effect.

How can I free up space of files which are deleted?

I did read [here](https://docs.ceph.com/en/pacific/dev/delayed-delete/) that cephfs has lazy deletion but I don't know whether this is what is happening in my case or there is another issue.
If it is lazy deletion then how can I confirm that and how can I trigger actual deletion? If it is not lazy deletion then what is the actual problem?

Please ask if any other data is required for troubleshooting. I am working on this for nearly 3 days now and totally out of ideas so any help is deeply appreciated.

**Edit 1: added more details**

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph osd df
ID  CLASS  WEIGHT   REWEIGHT  SIZE     RAW USE   DATA      OMAP     META     AVAIL    %USE  VAR   PGS  STATUS
 0    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.6 GiB   593 MiB    2 KiB  1.0 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  1.07   10      up
 1    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.1 GiB   544 MiB   19 KiB  559 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.03  0.71    9      up
 2    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.7 GiB   669 MiB    6 KiB  1.0 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.12   13      up
 4    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.6 GiB   742 MiB   26 KiB  918 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  1.07   13      up
13    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.7 GiB   596 MiB    4 KiB  1.2 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.15    8      up
 5    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.9 GiB   1.2 GiB   56 MiB  713 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.26   16      up
 6    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.6 GiB   407 MiB  124 MiB  1.1 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  1.04    9      up
 7    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.3 GiB   418 MiB   67 MiB  887 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  0.89   12      up
 8    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.1 GiB   667 MiB   73 MiB  372 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.03  0.72   15      up
 9    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.7 GiB   1.2 GiB    7 KiB  526 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.13   18      up
10    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.5 GiB   906 MiB    8 KiB  579 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  0.96   11      up
11    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.7 GiB   1.1 GiB    6 KiB  628 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.15   11      up
12    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.8 GiB   600 MiB   16 MiB  1.2 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.17   15      up
 3    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   2.8 GiB   1.6 GiB   37 MiB  1.2 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.08  1.86   17      up
14    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.6 GiB   857 MiB   37 KiB  781 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.04  1.06   12      up
15    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.9 GiB   1.4 GiB    2 KiB  499 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.05  1.26   12      up
16    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   2.2 GiB   972 MiB    1 KiB  1.2 GiB  3.6 TiB  0.06  1.44   15      up
17    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB  1002 MiB   981 MiB    8 KiB   20 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.03  0.65   17      up
18    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   935 MiB   915 MiB    3 KiB   20 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.02  0.60   17      up
19    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   1.0 GiB  1006 MiB      0 B   28 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.03  0.67   10      up
20    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   866 MiB   835 MiB      0 B   31 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.02  0.56   20      up
21    hdd  3.63869   1.00000  3.6 TiB   731 MiB   709 MiB      0 B   22 MiB  3.6 TiB  0.02  0.47   11      up
                       TOTAL   80 TiB    33 GiB    19 GiB  374 MiB   14 GiB   80 TiB  0.04
MIN/MAX VAR: 0.47/1.86  STDDEV: 0.01
```

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph fs status
new_storage - 4 clients
======================
RANK  STATE                      MDS                        ACTIVITY     DNS    INOS   DIRS   CAPS
 0    active  new_storage.cephserver2.gvflgv  Reqs:    0 /s   161    163     52    154
               POOL                   TYPE     USED  AVAIL
cephfs.new_storage.meta  metadata  79.4M  25.3T
cephfs.new_storage.data    data    18.2G  25.3T
               STANDBY MDS
new_storage.cephserver3.wxrhxm
new_storage.cephserver4.xwpidi
new_storage.cephserver1.fwjpoi
MDS version: ceph version 16.2.13 (5378749ba6be3a0868b51803968ee9cde4833a3e) pacific (stable)
```

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     dcad37bc-1185-11ee-88c0-7cc2556f5050
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 failed cephadm daemon(s)

  services:
    mon: 5 daemons, quorum cephserver1,cephserver2,cephserver3,cephserver4,cephserver5 (age 8d)
    mgr: cephserver2.sztiyq(active, since 2w), standbys: cephserver1.emjcaa
    mds: 1/1 daemons up, 3 standby
    osd: 22 osds: 22 up (since 3h), 22 in (since 8d)

  data:
    volumes: 1/1 healthy
    pools:   4 pools, 97 pgs
    objects: 1.81k objects, 6.2 GiB
    usage:   33 GiB used, 80 TiB / 80 TiB avail
    pgs:     97 active+clean

  io:
    client:   462 B/s rd, 0 op/s rd, 0 op/s wr
```

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph health detail
HEALTH_WARN 1 failed cephadm daemon(s)
[WRN] CEPHADM_FAILED_DAEMON: 1 failed cephadm daemon(s)
    daemon grafana.cephserver1 on cephserver1 is in error state
```

**Edit 2:** I forgot to mention an important point. The entire storage cluster is in an air gapped environment.

**Edit 3:** I tried to compact the OSDs online as per a suggestion in the comments from eblock and it partially worked. This is what `ceph df` was showing before compacting:

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph df
--- RAW STORAGE ---
CLASS    SIZE   AVAIL    USED  RAW USED  %RAW USED
hdd    80 TiB  80 TiB  **33 GiB**    **33 GiB**       0.04
TOTAL  80 TiB  80 TiB  **33 GiB**    **33 GiB**       0.04

--- POOLS ---
POOL                                ID  PGS   STORED  OBJECTS    USED  %USED  MAX AVAIL
device_health_metrics                1    1   17 MiB       29   50 MiB      0     25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.meta   8   32   26 MiB       28   79 MiB      0     25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.data   9   32   5.2GiB     1.42k  15 GiB   0.02     25 TiB
.nfs                                10   32  1.7 KiB        7   40 KiB      0     25 TiB
```

After compaction the 33GiB got reduced to 23GiB as shown below

```
[root@cephserver1 ~]# ceph df
--- RAW STORAGE ---
CLASS    SIZE   AVAIL    USED  RAW USED  %RAW USED
hdd    80 TiB  80 TiB  **23 GiB**    **23 GiB**       0.03
TOTAL  80 TiB  80 TiB  **23 GiB**    **23 GiB**       0.03

--- POOLS ---
POOL                                ID  PGS   STORED  OBJECTS     USED  %USED  MAX AVAIL
device_health_metrics                1    1   18 MiB       29   54 MiB      0     25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.meta   8   32   26 MiB       28   79 MiB      0     25 TiB
cephfs.new_storage.data   9   32   5.2GiB     1.42k  15 GiB   0.02     25 TiB
.nfs                                10   32   32 KiB        7  131 KiB      0     25 TiB
```

However, the data in the pools did not go down. So anymore suggestions are heartily appreciated.

**Edit 4:** I mounted CephFS natively (i.e. without NFS in between with kernel command) using the following command:

```
# mount -t ceph 172.30.0.31:6789,172.30.0.32:6789,172.30.0.33:6789:/ /cephmnt -o name=user1
```

After mounting I do `ls -a /cephmnt` but I don't see the old data. However, when I do `df -Th` on the client where CephFS is mounted then I get still see the space occupied by the old data (5.2GB). So my suspicion is that the problem is not with NFS.

Comment: Pacific is not entirely deprecated yet, there will be another update available soon (16.2.15). Maybe there's some cache involved showing you the "old" data when remounting? Can you mount it natively without NFS inbetween and see if it's still the same result? If you remount, is the data still present? Can you add more details to the question lile `ceph osd df`, `ceph -s` and `ceph fs status` output? You could be suffering from [tombstones](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/thread/X3CGYQJMHCUGSC7NYENCKEOD2YQ7NK4G/). Maybe try to compact the OSDs online?

Comment: Dear @eblock Huge thanks for your comment and suggestions. I have added the outputs you asked. Although I don't think it's a cache issue because of `ceph df` outputs but I will still try your suggestion and revert back. It will take me sometime though.

Comment: Dear @eblock I tried compacting the OSDs online using `ceph tell osd.<id> compact` and it partially solved the problem as mentioned in the question edit 3. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Dear @eblock I remounted CephFS natively (using kernel support) without NFS in between as you had suggested. It did not show me the old folder which I had earlied copied and deleted when mounted through NFS but it still does show that the space occupied by the old folder is not yet released. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the CephFs empty now? If it is supposed to be empty, I suppose you also still see objects with `rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls`, correct? Can you paste the output of `rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls | wc -l`?

Comment: @eblock you are right. I can see the objects with `rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls` command. However, just a few minutes ago some user copied a 1.3GB folder to the cluster. So the number of objects have increased to 1744 (using `rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls | wc -l`) from 1.42k (mentioned originally in the question) but the problem remains same. When I moved his folder using `mv <usr_data_dir> <another_usual_nfs>` to some other storage location I am still able to see 1744 objects (using `rados -p cephfs.new_storage.data ls | wc -l`).

Comment: If users are actually working on it you probably won't get an empty filesystem ;-)

Comment: Since it all happens asynchronously and users keep writing data into the pool while you move it away, you might never get down to 0 objects.

Comment: Dear @eblock there is only one user as of now. And he also will put data very infrequently. So I suspect that is not the reason. Is there a way to trigger deletion of objects in CephFS or ceph pools? As I said before I am out of ideas so anything is appreciated.

Comment: I can't really reproduce that, in my test clusters the data is immediately gone after a few seconds. Have you restarted services like mds (to provoke a failover to a different mds) or the mgr (ceph mgr fail), maybe it's stuck and the calculation is wrong? It happens with MGRs...